# Drupal 8 - How to add link & display in twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I have file in src/Form/TestForm.php.

I would like to add link of Forgot password in **buildForm** function & want to display in twig template file.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Elements inside the form should be added via the buildForm method and not in twig.

Comment: Also, the TestForm.php file should be placed under `src/Form/` and not `src/form/`

Comment: If you are having troubles then i suggest a tutorial such as http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8

Comment: Sorry @Eyal it's typo mistake in form. I already created Form. I just wanted to pass link from TestForm.php to Twig template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the link in the form builder, something like the following example:.

```
$forgot_password_link = \Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Password link'), 'user.pass')->toRenderable();
$form['forgot_password_link'] = [
  '#markup' => render($forgot_password_link),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add links in Twig directly:

```
<a href="{{ path('user.pass') }}">{{ 'Forgot password?'|t }}</a>
```

see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates